# VS-Code suppress C# suggestions with .editorconfig/OmniSharp

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, omnisharp, editorconfig

I am using the latest VS-Code build (1.50.1) and the EditorConfig & OmniSharp plugin (on an up to date Win10 machine).
In the C# code there are several blue squiggly lines indicating suggestions, some of them I try to hide/suppress/disable with an `.editorconfig` file.
Changing settings in the .editorcofig file and saving works (for example changing `indent_size` works immediately) - the `.editorconfig` file is loaded and recognized.

Now I want to suppress the
*CA1805* (Member 'Count' is explicitly initialized to its default value) and
*IDE0063* ('using' statement can be simplified) suggestions:

```
[*.cs]
#dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.severity = none
dotnet_diagnostic.CA1805.severity = none
dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.IDE0063.severity = none
```

This however, does not work, the suggestions don't change, even with a restart of Omnisharp or VSCode itself.
*However*, uncommenting the first line and disabling all analyzer diagnostics works upon saving the `.editorconfig` file.

**How do I suppress these suggestions in VS-Code & `.editorconfig`?**